# ¿Cómo quitar caracteres después de un espacio en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me ayudan a solucionar lo siguiente:

Tengo una columna con datos en el siguiente formato:

```
Columna
-----------
R1069 1
C584CP 1
```

Y quiero realizar una consulta que me los devuelva de la siguiente manera:

```
Columna
-----------
R1069
C584CP
```

Digo después del espacio, porque hay más datos con más caracteres antes del espacio.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
SUBSTRING(NombreColumna,1,
      case  when CHARINDEX(' ',NombreColumna)-1 < 0 
            then LEN(NombreColumna)
            else CHARINDEX(' ',NombreColumna)-1 end)
```

Gracias a todos por aportar.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar en el `SELECT` un `LEFT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(nombreColumna, charindex(' ', nombreColumna) - 1)
```

Puedes insertar un `CASE` por si se encuentra que alguna posición es 0 no le restes -1 y te de error.

```
LEFT(nombreColumna, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', nombreColumna) > 0 
                         THEN CHARINDEX(' ', nombreColumna) - 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END)
```

De esta forma coges la posición del espacio que tienes con un `charIndex` y coges todo lo que está antes de éste.

**Más info:**

1. [LEFT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ME arroja una error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.